# PHP MYSQL encoding issue ( Turkish Characters )

Tags: php, mysql

core.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

gamelisti.php

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM games");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
HTML CODES
<?php echo $row['game_name']; ?>
HTML CODES
<?php }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i use turkish characters like "ö,ç,ğ,ı" i see these correctly in database but when i select them from database and show with php echo they looks like question mark=(?)
my encoding on database utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Double check your HTML encoding.
2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php (just after you connect to DB: `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');`
3. Are you using prepared statements? (not related but important).

Comment: Thank you very much [[  mysqli_set_charset($db_connection, "utf8")  ]] solved my problem

Comment: I was having an issue with str_replace not working and this solved my issue, thanks!